# Can Azure front door be used as disaster management strategy for a web app hosted in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, replication, disaster-recovery, azure-front-door

I want to know if Azure front door be used for disaster management for a web app hosted in azure?

Reading the content around Azure front door, I understand that it can be used for following

1. Load balancing across regions i.e. global level which API management cannot do
2. WAF rules can be applied
3. acts as a CDN

Since it can be used for routing across multiple regions, I am not sure if having it in place is the solution for disaster recovery or some more steps need to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and it is mostly used for  creating high availability applications. You can deploy your web application in multiple other Azure regions for high availability. You can then use the Azure front door which can redirect traffic to the other if first region is unavailable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. So do I need to deploy any other service to take care of disaster management. or what are the other possible options.

Comment: There are different scenarios which you need to take care of for disaster management.  You can have data corruption , Failure of Dependent service and other.  
 https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/resiliency/resiliency-disaster-recovery-azure-applications.md